# I would like to know the Laplace Transform and/or Fourier Transform of this function

Tags: sequences-and-series, laplace-transform

Let $ c(t) = A \cdot\left( 1 + 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n e^{-B\cdot t \cdot n^2}  \right).$

Also known as

$A \vartheta _4 (0, e^{-Bt})$

(Jacobi's elliptic theta-function).

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Background info: the function c(t) is the flux  vs the time (t) of a gas permeating through a flat membrane

Comment: Rumplestillskin I tried numerical approaches, but ultimately I need an exact form for fitting purposes.

Comment: Oddly enough Carslaw, H. S., & Jaeger, J. C. (1959). Conduction of Heat in Solids 2nd Edition. Oxford University Press. https://doi.org/10.1063/1.3057871 has a solution for a COMPOSITE OF TWO membranes, but I am uncertain how to make it one.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/bVOeD It can be seen here. p is the complex frequency the rest of them are the parameters of the two slabs.

Comment: Why did I get downvotes?

Comment: The question is not posed very well. 1. It appears homework-like (although it would certainly be a difficult assignment). 2. There is no effort shown on your behalf at what you have tried, what you think etc.  On a side note, you ask for either/both a Laplace/Fourier integral transform representation? Are you familiar with both integral transforms?

Comment: I am familiar with the Fourier, and I know the basics of the Laplace.

Comment: @ catfishery : If you want that your question be not deleted soon, and if you expect more useful answers, use the "edit" button below your question and modify the wording, in taking account of the above comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a reminder :
$$\vartheta_4(0,x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^n x^{n^2}=1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n x^{n^2}$$
$$1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n x^{n^2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\vartheta_4(0,x)+1\right)$$
There is something wrong in the wording of the question :

> $ c(t) = A \cdot\left( 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n e^{-B\cdot t \cdot n^2}  \right) \quad$ 
>   Also known as 
>   $\quad A \vartheta _4 (0, e^{-Bt})$

First interpretation :
$$ c(t) = A \cdot\left( 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n e^{-B\cdot t \cdot n^2}  \right) =\frac{A}{2} \cdot\left(\vartheta_4\left(0,e^{-B\cdot t}\right)+1\right) $$ 
$$\text{which is not }\quad A \vartheta _4 (0, e^{-Bt})\quad\text{as stated.}$$

Second interpretation :
$$c(t)=A \vartheta _4 (0, e^{-Bt}) = A \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^n e^{-B\cdot t \cdot n^2}  $$
$$\text{which is not }\quad A \cdot\left( 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n e^{-B\cdot t \cdot n^2}  \right)\quad\text{as stated.}$$

Supposing that the second is the right one :

$\mathcal{L}_t\big[e^{-B\cdot t \cdot n^2}\big](p)=\frac{1}{B\:n^2+p}\quad$
where $\mathcal{L}$ denotes the Laplace transform.

So, the Laplace transform of $c(t)$ is :
$$\mathcal{L}_t\big[c(t)\big](p)=A \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{B\:n^2+p}$$

$$\mathcal{L}_t\big[c(t)\big](p)=\frac{\pi\:A}{\sqrt{B\:p}\:\sinh\left(\pi\sqrt{\frac{p}{B} }\right)} $$

Comment: Gret one, however, the formula I am sure of is the very first one.

Comment: Mistake or insufficient wording in a question makes time waste. More over, your question is put "on hold" now. It's a pity, I would have given the answer. I hope that you can find it by yourself with the above method.

Comment: Checking out the answers as soon as possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a good one. Since the solution is available for composite slabs, let's say this is a composite of two equal membranes, so in the image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l60sR.jpg

everything _1 = _2

therefore

$Q (s, C , D) = \dfrac{C}
{s l \sqrt{s/D} 
\cdot 
\cosh \left(
\dfrac{l}{2} 
\sqrt{\dfrac{s}{D}} 
\right)
\cdot 
\sinh\left(
\dfrac{l}{2} 
\sqrt{\dfrac{s}{D}} 
\right) }$

Comment: I must apologize everyone because I missed the 2 multiplicator before the sum. Corrected it.